# Can a running thread become runnable on entering a uncontested synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-state

There is a strange thing happening on our production box. 
Code functionality:
A UI servlet takes a monitor lock on the document object which is being actioned upon by the user and performs some computation on it. The monitor lock is acquired to prevent the same document object from getting modified concurrently by multiple users simultaneously.

Issue Observed in Prod:
Few user actions are getting timed out.

Log Analysis:
The thread corresponding to the timed out user actions is printing all logs prior to acquiring the monitor lock on the document object. Then there is a gap of over 1 hour where the thread is not surfacing up in the logs and then it suddenly becomes alive and does the computation and attempts to send back a response which obviously errors out as the HTTP request has already timed out.
We have checked the logs and code and can confirm that there is no other thread which had acquired the monitor lock on that particular document object. So the lock was uncontested at the point in question.

What could be the possible issue? Is it just that the thread was put into a Runnable state on encountering a synchronized block and for the next 60-80 mins, the CPU never got a chance to run this particular runnable thread?

Comment: "Is it just that the thread was put into a Runnable state on encountering a synchronized block and for the next 60-80 mins, the CPU never got a chance to run this particular runnable thread?" Sounds very unlikely to me.

Comment: You can use jstack to try to get more information.

Comment: What else happened immediately before the thread became alive again? Maybe there are other locks involved? If you get a stack trace dump, that will show all the locks the threads hold or wait for.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the application code is not messing around with thread priority via `Thread.setPriority()` method or the like. If you're using an IDE like IntelliJ and the Java sources are available, and assuming you can run the application and relevant flow locally in your development machine, you can put a breakpoint in `Thread.setPriority()` to see if anywhere it is getting invoked. This is an excerpt from Java Concurrency in Practice, Goetz 2006, regarding how unpredictable behavior can be if you try to set Thread priority manually:

> 10.3.1. Starvation 
>   Starvation occurs when a thread is perpetually denied access to resources it needs in order to make progress; the most 
>   commonly starved resource is CPU cycles. Starvation in Java applications can be caused by inappropriate use of thread 
>   priorities.  It  can  also be  caused  by  executing  nonterminating  constructs  (infinite  loops  or  resource waits  that do  not 
>   terminate) with a lock held, since other threads that need that lock will never be able to acquire it. 
>   The thread priorities defined in the Thread API are merely scheduling hints. The Thread API defines ten priority levels 
>   that the JVM can map to operating system scheduling priorities as it sees fit. This mapping is platformspecific, so two 
>   Java priorities can map to the same OS priority on one system and different OS priorities on another. Some operating 
>   systems have fewer than ten priority levels, in which case multiple Java priorities map to the same OS priority. 
>   Operating system schedulers go to great lengths to provide scheduling fairness and liveness beyond that required by the 
>   Java  Language  Specification.  In  most  Java  applications,  all  application  threads  have  the  same  priority,  Thread.
>   NORM_PRIORITY. The thread priority mechanism is a blunt instrument, and it's not always obvious what effect changing 
>   priorities will have; boosting a thread's priority might do nothing or might always cause one thread to be scheduled in 
>   preference to the other, causing starvation. 
>   It  is  generally  wise  to  resist  the temptation  to  tweak  thread  priorities.  As  soon  as  you  start  modifying  priorities,  the 
>   behavior of your application becomes platform specific and you introduce the risk of starvation. You can often spot a 
>   program  that  is  trying  to  recover  from  priority  tweaking  or  other  responsiveness  problems  by  the  presence  of 
>   Thread.sleep or Thread.yield calls in odd places, in an attempt to give more time to lower priority threads.[5]